# Consultar tablas de bases de datos en POSTGRES desde shell

Tags: postgresql, shell

¿Es posible realizar una consulta local desde shell a la base de datos postgres y que el resultado lo guarde en un texto plano?

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así poder ayudarte mejor, cual es tu error ? seria bueno que publicaras lo que has intentado o consultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar la option -t

```
psql -t -c "select datname from pg_database" > edward.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes copiar el resultado de un **SELECT** a un archivo, para esto debes ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
   psql copy (select * from nombre_tabla) to 'directorio_name/file_name.txt';
```

Esto permite copiar todos los datos obtenidos en el select al archivo ubicado en el directorio seleccionado.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero me aparece el siguiente mensaje al momento de ejecutar el shell el cual  tiene lo siguiente:
#!/bin/bash 
copy (select * from pg_database) to 'home/administrador/scripts/file_name.txt';
mensaje de error:
./edward.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `select'